# LIKE statement in blade laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to do a LIKE statement something like this:

```
     @foreach($data as $value) 
@if($value->name 'LIKE', '%' . $value->Name . '%')
 <th><a href="{{route('user.show',['id'=>$value->pi_id])}}"><span style="color: red;">{{$value->Name}}</span></a></th>
 @endif

@endforeach
```

But currently I am doing like this only:

```
    @foreach($data as $value) 
    @if(($value->name == $value->Name))
 <th><a href="{{route('user.show',['id'=>$value->pi_id])}}"><span style="color: red;">{{$value->Name}}</span></a></th>
 @endif
    @endforeach
```

Is this possible? I heard that I need to do something like  for the LIKE statement but it doesn't work.

$value-> name is from verifications table while $value->Name is from personal_infos table

Comment: what does that even mean?

Comment: Your foreach does nothing, it does not even output something, so what is the goal of it?

Comment: the name is from verification table while the Name is from personal_infos table, I want to do a LIKE statement between them in the blade. Is that possible? I can't really find anything similar or related to it on the internet

Comment: @Black sorry forgot to put something in

Comment: is `$value->Name` and `$value->name` are different ?

Comment: Question have been updated

Comment: @user2486 yup both are from different table that why I want to use the LIKE statement to relate together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should filter your data by query at first step and use `LIKE` there.

BTW, You can do it by `strpos`, `LIKE` is using in query, try like this

```
@if(strpos( $value->Name, $value->name))
```

Instead

```
@if($value->name 'LIKE', '%' . $value->Name . '%')
```

Comment: thank you for helping but doesn't seem to affect it, do you have another solution?

Comment: Sorry I think there might be something wrong with my controller, will get back to you after fixing it

Comment: @Dkna : It should work . did you check by putting value like `@if(strpos( 'my name is dkna', 'dkna'))` ?

Comment: I think it will work, it just that my controller has some issue now since the collection is showing something like this now, " 1 => {#341 ▼
      +"Name": "clarice"
      +"name": "John"
      +"created_at": "2017-11-30 06:02:26"
    }"

Comment: @Dkna : Try to put `LIKE` in your query ?

Comment: It will return an empty result, I am joining 2 tables together which are not related together at all and I just now saw someone saying it possible and I tried it but I didn't really check it now I am finding that again to check

Answer (score 3):

```
Illuminate\Support\Str::is($pattern, $value);
// Str::is("*{$value->Name}*", $value->name)

Illuminate\Support\Str::contains($haystack, $needle);
```

If this is case insensitive, `strtolower` the arguments.

`Str::is` [Laravel Docs - Helpers - str_is](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-str-is)

`Str::contains` [Laravel Docs - Helpers - str_contains](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-str-contains)

Comment: Then is contains case sensitive? @lagbox

Answer (score -1):

The other answer is the solution to the specific problem that's been asked, but the method used in the question isn't the right way to get what you want.

This filtering logic should not be placed in the view, so do that in the controller or service and only pass the list ov values which you can then output in the template without any conditions.